# How to use data or methods across different components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a HTML table in which in one component I have table head and other stuff and in other component I have tbody so in every row of `tbody` I am adding a delete row button which I want to delete but the data is in `thead`component there is no parent-child relation here so how can I do this.

**My code**

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  methods: {
    delete() {
      alert("tedt")
    }
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Here I have two components In one component delete button is the I know how to delete the row in same component by using this:

```js
delete(index) {
  console.log("Removing", index);
  this.tableDatas.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: You should watch tutorials about Vue. It will make you a better Dev. There is plenty of them. vueshcool.io, vuemastery.

Answer (score 1):

Vue Mixins will work for your problem.

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

Here is an example;

```
// define a mixin object
var myMixin = {
  created: function () {
    this.hello()
  },
  methods: {
    hello: function () {
      console.log('hello from mixin!')
    }
  }
}

// define a component that uses this mixin
var Component = Vue.extend({
  mixins: [myMixin]
})

var component = new Component() // => "hello from mixin!"
```

Comment: @dheerajkumar: you are encouraged to try this yourself. It is the best way to learn.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Shared events to catch between parent to component

```
var sharedEvents = new Vue();---declare on top of the vue instance 

//parent
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  ---code--

  methods:
     getData(){
     //emit the data in parent like this 
         sharedEvents.$emit('forceInjectGridData', {id: "billing-grid", data: data});
     }

  });
```

And catch the data in component like below wherever you want:

```
 methods:{
  forceInjectGridData(v) {

            if (this.id === v.id) {
                this.gridData = v.data;
              //do your coding here 
            }
        },

 } ,
  mounted(){
   sharedEvents.$on('forceInjectGridData', this.forceInjectGridData);
   }
```

Comment: is there any way to do it with vuex, as I am using vuex for state ,management